# How do I ascertain the key length of some Diffie Hellman moduli to counteract the Log Jam vulnerability?

Tags: diffie-hellman, logjam

I have the following Diffie-Hellman ciphers on one of my servers

```
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256     
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA        
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA      
TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

I have been asked to disable  any and al Diffie-Hellman moduli of less than 2048 bits

I've managed to find out that found the out that:

```
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA 
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
```

have a bit length of 1024  but I'm really struggling to find what the actual bit length is of the first 4 ciphers that I mentioned..I've been searching the internet but I just can't find anything?

Am I missing anything? Any help gratefully received

Comment: To be clear: you've checked somehow for those 2 DHE_RSA suites the DHE group is 1024 bits (not that the RSA cert is)? If so the server very likely uses the same group for DHE_DSS if it supports DHE_DSS at all (which would only be so if it has a DSA key-and-cert configured, and DSA certs are rare, other than selfsigned ones used in older Java -- and older Java never did DHE over 768). In any case, either look at the server software/configuration, or connect to it and see what you get e.g. with `openssl s_client`. Not posting as answer because this isn't really within the topic of this Stack.

Comment: This depends on your implementation. E.g. if you have a Java server, you'd want to set the system parameter `jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048`

Comment: hi, which stack should I post it in?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I missing anything?

Actually, within the TLS protocol, the DH group used is not tied to the ciphersuite (even for ciphersuites that specify the use of DH); instead, those are negotiated separately (for DHE ciphersuites, the server proposes it within the ServerKeyExchange handshake).

I don't know what configurability your implementation has with regards to what DH groups is proposes/accepts - however, disabling specific ciphersuites may not be the correct method.  Your implementation might have a built-in assumption that "for this specific ciphersuite, we always use that specific DH group" - that would not be my first guess.